# C# Console Application: Visual Studio Can Not Find the Config File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I see in [Best practices for deploying passwords and other sensitive data to ASP.NET and Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure) that I can place my sensitive information in a separate file using this syntax:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config"></connectionStrings>
```

Being happy that `configSource` supports relative path and considering the fact that I am working on MAC, I ignored the file in git and I put the file in the upper directory: `../myconfig.config`. Build was fine. I ran the `Program.cs` and bam!

> Unable to open configSource file
>   '/Users/a/long/path/myProj/myProj/bin/Debug/../myconfig.config'.

So does it mean I have to put the path relative to the `bin/Debug` directory? I know that my config is already copied in bin directory with a different name. What baffles me is that why such a simple task (using another config file out of git) should be so complex. I have seen suggestions like running post-build commands to copy the config file. I thought it's too much for a simple inclusion of a config file.

I do not have a `C#` experience. I'm just trying to remove bunch of passwords from github.

Comment: Paths can be evaluated in two ways: either from the startup directory, or from the directory in which the executable is located. I assume for the .config that'll probably the latter. But that bin/debug/ folder happens to _be_ where your exe file is located when you build it, you know... so obviously, when starting the program in there, the path will be relative to that folder.

Comment: You cite **myconfig.config** in your error message but your XML code show that your configSource is named **ConnectionStrings.config**. Where do you reference **myconfig.config**?

Comment: @Nyerguds prepended the config file with `../../` and code works fine. I don't know about the actual build (exe file) yet.
@Jazimov first example is copied from microsoft documentation page.

Comment: Well obviously , but you can't rely on that since the final used program won't have your project folder. Just remove the ../ stuff and put the config file in the same folder as your exe file. There's an option in settings of files inside a project (solution explorer -> select a file -> ctrl+enter) to mark them to be copied to the output folder on build.

Comment: @Nyerguds what you said works fine. I'm just thinking if there is any way to add the config as a dll or some other encrypted file.

Comment: The point of a config is that it's user-editable, and that, in case secure access is needed, the user can put _their_ secure access information in there. If you don't want to give the user the access information of the dtabase itself, you'll need to make a public web service for connecting to your database which only gives access to exactly the things you want to give access to, and if you want to make sure not just anyone can use that, you'll need to work with some kind of account-based system with login information. None of which has any connection to your original question though.